# Why does Ubuntu's Unity Desktop take so long to Log Out?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity, ubuntu-12.10

You can install almost any other desktop onto Ubuntu 12.10, and it will logout way quicker than the Unity desktop does:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1074758

Why is this, and what can I do about it (besides not use unity)?

Comment: Not anymore. :)

Comment: @terdon, how did you see the low accept ratio ? where is it ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana when I posted the comment, it was visible under the OP's name. This is no longer the case but you can still check a user's questions on their page and those with accepted answers are highlighted.